# My call_function is not working Correctly with if else condition with python 2.6

Tags: python

I have learned & tried to create the two Functions in my below code, Where the First function is designed to Check the various process Status like ntp,nscd etc.
Now While executing the scripts the `call_function` not giving the correct Status of the process and Just returning with eg `NTP Service is Not Running On the host` for each Service. While Second Function `fs_function` which is created for FS usage is working correctly.

Can you guys suggest, What mistake i'm doing here..
Below is the Code..

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import socket
threshold = 9
hst_name = (socket.gethostname())
print "HostName:", hst_name

############### Function to Check the Different process & Service Status #########

def call_function(service):
   return subprocess.call('ps -e | grep service > /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)

ps_ntp = call_function("ntp")
ps_nscd = call_function("nscd")
ps_mail = call_function("sendmail")
ps_altris = call_function("aex-plug")
ps_automnt = call_function("automount")

if ps_ntp == 0:
    print "Service Status:  NTP Service is Running On the host" , hst_name
else:
   print  "Service Status:  NTP Service is Not Running On the host" , hst_name

if ps_nscd == 0:
   print "Service Status:  NSCD Service is Running On the host" , hst_name
else:
   print "Service Status:  NSCD Service is Not Running On the host", hst_name

if ps_mail == 0:
   print "Service Status:  Sendmail Service is Running On the host" , hst_name
else:
   print "Service Status:  Sendmail Service is Not Running" , hst_name

if ps_altris == 0:
   print "Service Status:  Altris Service is Running On the host" , hst_name
else:
   print "Service Status:  Altris Service is Not Running On the host" , hst_name

if ps_automnt == 0:
   print "Service Status:  Automount Service is Running On the host" , hst_name
else:
   print "Service Status:  Automont Service is Not Running On the host" , hst_name

####### Fucntion to Check the File-system thereshold Status #############

def fs_function(usage):
   return subprocess.Popen(['df', '-h', usage], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

rootfs = fs_function("/")
varfs  = fs_function("/var")

output = rootfs.communicate()[0].strip().split("\n")
for x in output[1:]:
    if int(x.split()[-2][:-1]) >= threshold:
        print "Service Status:  Filesystem For Root(/) is more than 90% On the Host" , hst_name
    else:
        print "Service Status:  Filesystem For Root(/) is Normal on The Host", hst_name

output = varfs.communicate()[0].strip().split("\n")
for x in output[1:]:
    if int(x.split()[-2][:-1]) >= threshold:
        print "Service Status:  Filesystem For /var is more than 90% On the Host" , hst_name
    else:
        print "Service Status:  Filesystem For /var  is Normal on The Host", hst_name
```

Comment: The `grep service` in your string doesn't use the `service` variable. You're telling `grep` to look for the literal text `service`, not `ntp` or `nscd` or whatever.

Comment: Please edit your question into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with extra emphasis on the _minimum_.. Also, please be aware that using `shell=True` is a well known security hazard

Comment: @SB87, Sure, i'll take care.

Comment: @user2357112, Well said .. i got it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this string formatting method:

```
return subprocess.call('ps -e | grep %s > /dev/null 2>&1' % service, shell=True)
```

Comment: I'll Check the suggested change and revert you on the status.